# SearchResultCollection to CSV

Tags: c#, active-directory

Is there any easy way to export the contents of my results (SearchResultCollection) to a CSV file?

or do I have to Iterate each result and Append it to a text file?

Comment: Iterate the result and append it to a text file.

Comment: @TimSchmelter post your response as an answer so I can give you credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any easy way to export the contents of my results
>   (`SearchResultCollection`) to a CSV file or do I have to Iterate each
>   result and Append it to a text file?

No, there is no better option than iterating the [`SearchResultCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresultcollection.aspx) and writing it to a text-file.

```
using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(path))
{
    foreach (SearchResult result in allSearchResults)
    {
         w.WriteLine(string.Format("Path={0} Properties={1}"
             , result.Path
             , string.Join(",", result.Properties.PropertyNames));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is MUCH more elegant than mine. I setup a ton of local variables and then used StreamWriter to WriteLine