# Saving LDAP search result in csv

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I am reading active director user information than i want to save to csv file.

```
DirectoryEntry de=new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://xxxx.com, xxxx, xxxx,     AutentniciationTypes.Secure");
DirectorySearcher ds=new DirectorySearcher(de);
ds.Filter="(&(objectClass=user)(I="+ "xxxx"));
SearchhResultCollection results=ds.FindAll();
```

Next i would like to save the "results"  to csv file. Please let me known to do it. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for the same as in this question 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594416/searchresultcollection-to-csv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18598274/1966993)

Iterate through the SearchResultCollection and write to a text-file as mentioned in above link.